# DNN Search customization

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-7

How do I edit the default text 'Search...' that appears inside my search bar? I am using DNN 7.1

Here is my skin object:

`<dnn:SEARCH ID="dnnSearch" runat="server" ShowSite="false" ShowWeb="false" EnableTheming="true" Submit="Search" CssClass="SearchButton" />`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the text Search... In file `admin\Skins\App_LocalResources\Search.ascx.resx`
in setting `Placeholder.Text`

Answer (score 0):

you can change from here see the above highlighted portion.[image]